# [Discord.js]MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have A Some Problem.
I spent three days trying to fix this, but I didn't succeed.
I need your help.

My Error Code is

```
C:\Discord Bot\My BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:415
    if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);
                                        ^

RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.
    at Function.verifyString (C:\Discord Bot\My BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:415:41)
    at Function.normalizeField (C:\Discord Bot\My BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:518:19)
    at C:\Discord Bot\My BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:539:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Function.normalizeFields (C:\Discord Bot\My BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:538:8)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (C:\Discord Bot\My BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:324:42)
    at MessageEmbed.addField (C:\Discord Bot\My BOT\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:315:17)
    at C:\Discord Bot\My BOT\src\commands\vatsim\atc.js:57:6
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'
}
```

My Code is

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    var ICAO = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ').toUpperCase()
    
    fetch(`https://data.vatsim.net/v3/vatsim-data.json`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

    let atc = data.controllers.find(Data => Data.callsign === `${ICAO}`);
    let cid = atc.cid
    let name = atc.name
    let facility = atc.facility
    let callsign = atc.callsign
    let frequency = atc.frequency
    let rating = atc.rating
    let server = atc.server
    let range = atc.visual_range
    let atis = atc.text_atis
    let last_update = atc.last_updated
    let logon_time = atc.logon_time
    
    const ok = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle(`️ **${ICAO} - ATC INFO**`)
    .addField(' CID', cid, true)
    .addField(' NAME', name, true)
    .addField(' CALLSIGN', callsign, true)
    .addField('️ FREQUENCY', frequency, true)
    .addField('✅ RATING', rating, true)
    .addField(' FACILITY', `FACILITY : ${fac}`, true)
    .addField('️ SERVER', `SERVER : ${server}`, true)
    .addField('️ RANGE', `RANGE : ${range}`, true)
    .addField('✉️ TEXT ATIS', atis)
    .addField('⏲️ LOGON_TIME', logon_time, true)
    .addField('⏲️ LAST_UPDATE', last_update, true)
    .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator} • Via VATSIM API`);
    message.channel.send({embeds: [ok]})
    
        }).catch(e => {
            const fail = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setColor('RED')
              .setTitle('❌ ERROR')
              .setDescription(`The controller you found ${ICAO} is not online. Please check the callsign again!`)
              .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`);

            return message.channel.send({embeds: [fail]})
    })
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "atc",
    aliases: ['ATC']
}
```

My Discord.js Ver Is 13.4.0 DEV

I try to install node-fetch ver 3.X Or above, I failed.(Using Import) So I'm currently using the 2.6.1 version.

Thanks For Your help

Comment: Just so you know, on StackOverflow the syntax highlighting uses the tags to find the correct language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the field values to strings

```js
const ok = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle(`️ **${ICAO} - ATC INFO**`)
    .addField(' CID', cid?.toString(), true)
    .addField(' NAME', name.toString(), true)
    .addField(' CALLSIGN', callsign.toString(), true)
    .addField('️ FREQUENCY', frequency.toString(), true)
    .addField('✅ RATING', rating.toString(), true)
    .addField(' FACILITY', `FACILITY : ${fac.toString()}`, true)
    .addField('️ SERVER', `SERVER : ${server.toString()}`, true)
    .addField('️ RANGE', `RANGE : ${range.toString()}`, true)
    .addField('✉️ TEXT ATIS', atis.toString())
    .addField('⏲️ LOGON_TIME', logon_time.toString(), true)
    .addField('⏲️ LAST_UPDATE', last_update.toString(), true)
    .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator} • Via VATSIM API`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the values extracted are numbers, but the embed only take non-empty *strings* as the 2 first arguments for fields.

You need to get Strings for the 2 values you are not concatenating to strings like so:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    var ICAO = message.content.split(' ').slice(1).join(' ').toUpperCase()
    
    fetch(`https://data.vatsim.net/v3/vatsim-data.json`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {

    let atc = data.controllers.find(Data => Data.callsign === `${ICAO}`);
    let cid = atc.cid
    let name = atc.name
    let facility = atc.facility
    let callsign = atc.callsign
    let frequency = atc.frequency
    let rating = atc.rating
    let server = atc.server
    let range = atc.visual_range
    let atis = atc.text_atis
    let last_update = atc.last_updated
    let logon_time = atc.logon_time
    
    const ok = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('GREEN')
    .setTitle(`️ **${ICAO} - ATC INFO**`)
    .addField(' CID', String(cid), true) // Here
    .addField(' NAME', name, true)
    .addField(' CALLSIGN', callsign, true)
    .addField('️ FREQUENCY', frequency, true)
    .addField('✅ RATING', String(rating), true) // Here
    .addField(' FACILITY', `FACILITY : ${fac}`, true)
    .addField('️ SERVER', `SERVER : ${server}`, true)
    .addField('️ RANGE', `RANGE : ${range}`, true)
    .addField('✉️ TEXT ATIS', atis)
    .addField('⏲️ LOGON_TIME', logon_time, true)
    .addField('⏲️ LAST_UPDATE', last_update, true)
    .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator} • Via VATSIM API`);
    message.channel.send({embeds: [ok]})
    
        }).catch(e => {
            const fail = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
              .setColor('RED')
              .setTitle('❌ ERROR')
              .setDescription(`The controller you found ${ICAO} is not online. Please check the callsign again!`)
              .setFooter(`Requested by ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`);

            return message.channel.send({embeds: [fail]})
    })
}

module.exports.config = {
    name: "atc",
    aliases: ['ATC']
}
```

Comment: Sadlly, It was not work.